# Using Github with FTP-simple in VS Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, ftp

this is maybe a really stupid question, but I don't know the answer to it. I have the code for a website I'm working on on a server and installed ftp-simple in Visual Studio Code, so it automatically downloads (to a folder on my pc) and uploads files while I'm working on them.

My problem is that only the files I am working on get downloaded, the ones I don't work on are just empty. When I want to commit this folder to github, of course those empty ones replace the "real" ones I commited prior.

So I guess my question is, how do you use github while working with FTP?